# Execute multiple select queries at a time in toad

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am tying to execute multiple select statements at a time in `Toad for Oracle` to compare two tables and develop some logic but it is throwing some error.

I searched through net and I found suggestions to execute multiple `insert`statements by putting them in between `begin` and `end` but same thing is not working for `select` queries.

Finally, what I want is to print two tables by executing two select queries at a time like selecting two `select` queries and clicking `F5` in SQL Server.

Comment: We cannot see what you are doing wrong if you don't put your script in your question my friend....i do not have a crystal ball :P

Comment: select * from kk_dept; select * from kk_emp; i want to execute these two queries at a time, can u tell me how to do it in toad.

Comment: Try `SELECT  (SELECT * FROM   kk_dept) AS kk_dept (SELECT * FROM kk_emp) AS kk_emp` not sure if this works but you can try, also i am not too sure about your second question as i dont use toad

Comment: from keyword missing, I am not getting where to write from keyword

Comment: Well as i am fairly new to SQL i will have to leave someone else to answer this for you....Good Luck

Comment: @karun What is the exact error message you are getting when you try to run your original two statements in Toad via F5 (or via the "Run as script" button)? I assume you have the two statements on separate lines?

Comment: @Boneist, I selected these two select * from kk_dept;select * from kk_emp; queries and clicking F5/Execute script then I am getting only one grid that is dept table.

Comment: Did you try highlighting both queries and then running as a script?

Comment: ya I highlighted two queries then clicked execute as script

Comment: I did the same in sql server it worked fine I got two tables it is very useful when we are writing joins by seeing both tables but now I am trying to achieve the same in toad but not getting

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  If this is SQL Server, why do I see Oracle tag????

Comment: @Eric, the question is not about any functionality I am trying to know the equivalent of one of the features of sql server management studio in toad, just i wanted to circulate the question to both the people, May be anyone faced the same problem like me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to write your 2 select statements, with a semicolon in between. Then hit F5 (Execute as script). In the Script Output window, you will have 4 tabs : Output, Errors, Grid1, Grid2. Grid1 and Grid2 are the results of your 2 select statements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that execute as script performs a full return of all data and you may run into out of memory errors with large data sets. - EDIT: I just caught the SQL Server reference and the Oracle tag. This comment in regards to Toad Oracle.

Comment: ya I did the same but I am getting one grid only are u sure u r getting two grids?

Comment: I am not giving space between two queries in editor that is the problem anyway its working now.

Answer (score 1):

> I got two tables it is very useful when we are writing joins by seeing both table

As far as I can tell, you can't see such an output in a "parallel manner" using **one** Editor window. Therefore, open **two** Editors (use the appropriate toolbar button)!

Arrange them (resize, place them side by side or, eventually, one above the other) and run `SELECT`s one by one. Each output will be in its own "Data Grid" and you'll be able to compare them.